# getAllPrebidWinningBids() returns something but getAllWinningBids() is empty

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I've been struggling with `pbjs` and `DFP` for several days now and my current problem is the one described in the title: when I type `pbjs.getAllPrebidWinningBids()` in the console, something is returned but nothing is displayed on my test page, and when I type `pbjs.getAllWinningBids()`, an empty array is returned and I don't get why.

A few more info :

- This is a test page on our server with no other competition;
- We use custom price buckets;
- In DFP, I have 5 line items from 0.00€ to 2.00€ (so a 0.50€ increment) that matches the custom price buckets in the code;
- The bids are "redirected" in the correct price buckets;
- The code works and an ad is displayed when I set up a self-promotion
  campaign in DFP with a prebid snippet as a creative, so I suppose
  that something is wrong with the price buckets.

Would someone have an idea of what is blocking the selection of the bid and the rendering?

Thanks!

**EDIT :** I've come to realize that it was actually a normal behaviour since `pbjs.getAllPrebidWinningBids()` returns the bids that won the auction but haven't rendered on the page yet, while `pbjs.getAllWinningBids()` returns those that won but have also rendered.
So my question now is why the hell is no ad rendered at all?!

Here's my code (with a few dummy values), in case someone understand what's wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/8ewz9rgb/2/

Comment: your JSfiddle example doesn't seem to be setup correctly. The `prebid1.38.0.js` file returns a 404

Comment: Indeed it's just the html code to show you what it looks like, the `prebid1.38.0.js` file is only on our server.

But I don't think that's the problem since this code works with a house campaign, right? As one of the main differences between house and price-priority campaigns is the price bucket, that's why I suppose that's the problem. :/

Answer (score -1):

Not answering the original thread question, instead your new issue why no ads are rendering. This is because you are calling GPT's googletag.disableInitialLoad. This will not render ads until googletag.refresh is called, which doesn't happen because it's in a 'pbjs' queue and you are not loading Prebid here, it is 404ing.